# Creating a button in Javascript to save the value switch after refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a button to switch between status issue and no issue. Also the page is going to have a 60 second refresh. I am having a couple issues.
1. The first issue is that after my button switches from no issue to issue it does not save the status after the refresh. So after the 60 seconds it automatically goes back to its default value which was issue. I want it to refresh and hold its value.

2. The second issue is that my button only goes from Issue to No-issue and it doesn't interchange between the two.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- ******************************************Refresh************************************* -->

   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60">



<!-- ******************************************BUTTON************************************* -->
    <button id="btn" type="button"value= "edit">Switch Status</button>

    <script>
                document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById('No_Issue').innerHTML = document.getElementById('stu').innerHTML;
        }
    </script>  
  </h1>
<p>


<!--/************************************** No Issue Style***********************************/ -->
    <div id = "No_Issue" style="float:left; width:48%;">  

      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <strong><img alt="" src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/J/t/o/U/t/blue-thumbs-up-md.png" 
                     style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
        <Strong><font size="6">Status: No Issue</font></Strong></p>
    </div>

  <div style="display:none; text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">




<!--//**************************************Issue Style*********************************** -->


    <div id="stu" style="float:left; width:48%;">  
      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <img alt=""    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg/240px- Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg.png"
             style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
          <Strong><font size="6">Status: Issue</font></Strong>
                </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When a page refreshes like you have here, It is essentially getting a new copy of the page and displaying it. There is no state saved. If you want state saved, you need to use some server side coding to store the state on the server, and then dynamically inject that state during the page load.

Comment: Any suggestions on how or what I should research for that ?

Comment: javascript with ajax, or html with forms. Then on the server side, it depends on what your server supports: php maybe.

So you'd have your page you show up there "index.php" then you have another page that is just for forms submission or ajax "storedata.php". Then when you click the button, send the new value to storedata.php, which will store the data somehow, maybe a database or a text file. Then when your "index.php" page loads, retrieve that value and send it to the page that is created for the user.

Comment: If the data is per user, you don't want to send it to the server, you want to store it on the user's machine, one way is cookies another is web storage https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **jQuery to toggle between the statuses**. I have modified the script of yours as below.

As for the saving of the status of after page refresh, you should acknowledge **AJAX** or use the **localstorage** to save the value of the status.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").on('click', function(){
    $("#No_Issue").toggle();
    $("#Issue").toggle();
  })
})
</script>

<style>
#No_Issue{
  display: block
 }
 
#Issue{
  display: none
 }
</style>
<body>
<!-- ******************************************Refresh************************************* -->

   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60">



<!-- ******************************************BUTTON************************************* -->
    <button id="btn" type="button"value= "edit">Switch Status</button>

<p>


<!--/************************************** No Issue Style***********************************/ -->
    <div id = "No_Issue" style="float:left; width:48%;">  

      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <strong><img alt="" src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/J/t/o/U/t/blue-thumbs-up-md.png" 
                     style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
        <Strong><font size="6">Status: No Issue</font></Strong></p>
    </div>

  <div id ="Issue" style=" text-align:center;margin-
              top:15px; margin-bottom:5px; max-
              width:605px;">




<!--//**************************************Issue Style*********************************** -->


    <div id="stu" style="float:left; width:48%;">  
      <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black; height:80px">
        <img alt=""    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg/240px- Stop_hand_nuvola_orange.svg.png"
             style="width: 45px; height: 45px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
          <Strong><font size="6">Status: Issue</font></Strong>
                </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you put this all into an html? not separate the CSS and JS please

Comment: suzan why are they not formatted the same?    <div id="stu" style="float:left; width:48%;">   is included in the issues but not in the no issues. When I try to manually input it I get an error